# Amazon EC2 instance not able to access via ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am not able to access my amazon ec2 instance via ssh using putty and git bash. The webpage that it is linked to is working and I am able to connect to it.

The ec2 instance is a ubuntu machine. All the security rules are set properly. I also found that the instance is not listening on port 22. Maybe that is the problem but then how can I access it without using Putty?

Any and all help will be appreciated.....

Comment: Is the Port 22 open in your security group? And what error are you getting when you SSH to the instance

Comment: If you are using putty you need to generate .ppk file and assign. There is a puTTygen.exe. Instructions can be found here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: I am connecting using a .ppk file only. My seciruty group is set to all traffic. When i ssh it says Network Error:connection refused.